# Spark: how to handle keys containing dot (or period), abc.xyz

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large file with repeating JSON lines as shown below:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "key2": [
            {
                "key3": {
                    "key4": {
                        "abc.xyz": "some_value"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am able to read the file using pyspark:

df = spark.read.json('sample.json')
How can I flatten this df,

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, ArrayType

```
def flatten(df):
    # compute Complex Fields (Lists and Structs) in Schema   
    complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType) for field in df.schema.fields
if type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
    while len(complex_fields)!=0:
        col_name=list(complex_fields.keys())[0]  
        # if StructType then convert all sub element to columns.
        if (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == StructType):
            expanded = [F.col(col_name+'.'+k).alias(col_name+'_'+k) for k in [ n.name for n in complex_fields[col_name]] ]
            df=df.select("*", *expanded).drop(col_name)
        # if ArrayType then add the Array Elements as Rows using the explode function
        elif (type(complex_fields[col_name]) == ArrayType):
            df=df.withColumn(col_name,F.explode_outer(col_name))
        # recompute remaining Complex Fields in Schema       
        complex_fields = dict([(field.name, field.dataType) for field in df.schema.fieldsif type(field.dataType) == ArrayType or  type(field.dataType) == StructType])
    return df
```

Using this function resulted in this error:

> AnalysisException: [FIELD_NOT_FOUND] No such struct field `xyz` in `xyz`.`abc`.

How can I successfully flatten nested JSON data which has keys containing dot i.e. "."?

Comment: Try wrapping your object names in backticks (  `  )

Comment: flattened_df = df.selectExpr("key1", "explode(key1.key2) AS key2").selectExpr("key1", "key2.key3 AS key3")

# Extract values from keys containing dots
flattened_df = flattened_df.withColumn("abc_xyz", get_json_object("key3", "$.`abc.xyz`"))

Comment: @Andrew could you give an example?